# c++ error in if else statement, what is wrong with my syntax?

Tags: c++

Im getting the following errors in my if else statement. What is wrong with the syntax?

ass4.cpp:46: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘int’ in return
ass4.cpp:49: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘else’

```
 41    if ((type_f == 1) && (type_s == 1))
 42          {
 43          cout << "11" << endl;
 44 
 45          // 1 1 = iterative, reverse
 46          return reverse(str_input);
 47          }
 48 
 49    if else((type_f == 1) && (type_s == 2))
 50          {
 51          cout << "12" << endl;
 52 
 53          return palin_l(str_input);
 54          }
```

Comment: We need more context here. Can you post a complete, self-contained example that lets us get the error?

Comment: Well, evidently, you're returning a string instead of an int.

Comment: and you probably meant `else if` instead of `if else`

Comment: Do note there is a `std::reverse`, too.

Comment: @chris which he is probably using ^^

Answer (score 2):

```
if else((type_f == 1) && (type_s == 2))
^^^^^^^
```

Is not valid syntax, update to

```
else if ((type_f == 1) && (type_s == 2))
```

Also it complains about comparing `string` to `int` type, is `type_s` string type?

Comment: error message may come from invalid syntax, have you updated `if else` to `else if`? Does it fix something?

Comment: It's not complaining about the comparison; it's about the return of reverse on line 46.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your function defined to return `int`?  Does `reverse` return a `std::string`?  That's not going to work.  Change one or the other.
2. `if else` is not legal syntax.  From what you have there, it looks like you should switch to `else if`.